# Real Time Tension Measurement of a string

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life, string

For a cable-stayed bridge, I have come across some papers where it is mentioned that the tension is varying in real time. I was just wondering why the cable tension is changed? (All the derivations I have found assume that the cable tension is constant)

Comment: Can you attach a link to some those papers which say the tension varies? Maybe they're considering some certain circumstances.

Comment: Varying load on the bridge, forces due to wind, bridge “swinging”, etc?

Comment: https://ascelibrary.org/doi/abs/10.1061/(ASCE)ST.1943-541X.0001337

Comment: The cable tension will certainly vary in reality: the weight of passing vehicles deform the bridge and will increase the tension in the cables for the bridge to remain quasi-static, the wind causes oscillations (sometimes so strong ones that bridges collapse), thermal expansion causes stresses, etc. The question is how pronounced each of the effects is.

Comment: The bridge can be subjected to any kind of load. The objective is to find the cable tension using some accelerometers in the cables. So what they do, from the accelerometers, they get the fundamental frequency and hence calculate the tension. What I understand, the fundamental frequency is the property of the cable and does not depend on the forcing function.

Comment: @SebastianRiese , So the natural frequency will also change in real time right?

Comment: Yes, but I would guess not too much (since cars are probably considerable lighter than the car deck, even if the bridge is highly loaded). Deformations due to external forces (wind) will not change the eigenfrequencies in the harmonic regime.

Comment: I almost forgot to link this impressive illustration of what varying loads due to wind can do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-zczJXSxnw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cable tension varies because there are a lot of varying loads on the bridge: wind & the load from what it's designed to carry, for instance.

These loads are a big deal because bridges are made to be strong enough to carry the loads they are designed for but not enormously stronger than that, because making them enormously stronger than they need to be means that they are very expensive.

Further, they are designed to support the loads *people predicted when they were built* and those predictions are not always correct: the [Forth road bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_Road_Bridge) (now the old Forth road bridge) is a good example of this: it ended up carrying loads significantly greater than it was designed for, which was quite bad for it & resulted in structural problems requiring the rather urgent construction of the new bridge (the old bridge was partially (and I think fully) closed for a while from late 2015, before the new bridge was anywhere near complete, after structural problems were found).

It's not simple to measure the tension in cables because it's so enormous: you can't just stick some tension-measuring thing in the cable because it needs to be as strong as the cable.  The way the tension varies in time also contributes to fatigue failures of course, so, if you want a good picture of what may be happening to the cables, you need a good record of the way tension in them varies over time.

Traditionally you measure tension I think by measuring the changes in length of the cable (or of sections of it).  The [paper you reference](https://ascelibrary.org/doi/abs/10.1061/(ASCE)ST.1943-541X.0001337) appears to be proposing a way of measuring tension based on modelling the vibrations of the cable which it suggests may be cheaper.